# Difference between client class and service class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

What are client classes and a service class in a .net application and what is the difference between them ?

Comment: Would you be able to provide more context to your question? Sounds like it's not purely related to .NET, but rather to service designs/architecture.

Comment: How client and service classes are implemented in the context of a .net  web application.

Comment: take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547119.aspx

Comment: Think of it like going to an accountant to get your taxes done. The accountant is the service provider (class) and you are the client (class). You have a business transaction to complete and your account can make that happen.

Comment: Can you give examples of them? Is this related to WCF?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both *client* and *service* are **super-overloaded terms**, so they can mean lots of different things, depending on context.

As a general rule, though, the terms can be used to describe the **relationship between caller and callee**.

Given any two objects that interact, the object making a method call is a **client**, and the object being invoked is the **service**.

Depending on context, an object can be both a client and a service, since a call stack is usually deeper than two calls.

Answer (score 5):

you are buying a vehicle from Yamaha, then you want a regular service to your vehicle, so you will be the client(Client class) of Yamaha and Yamaha(service class) will be your service provider for you.